# Помогите добавить товары в MySQL и OpenCart

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, cms, opencart

Никак не могу понять. Есть файл csv, где база из 10 тысяч товаров (http://savepic.ru/11935819.jpg). Там 25 столбиков.
И есть БД MySQL и OpenCart2 на хостинге. 
По умолчанию там есть некий интернет-магазин и соответственно БД уже наполнена (http://savepic.ru/11980874.jpg)
Я никак не могу понять как мне весь мой список занести в БД вместо того, что там есть. Я сделал таблицу в MySQL, назвал myshop, и там добавил все эти 25 пунктов. (http://savepic.ru/11954250.jpg) Но потом понял, что это вообще бред и не знаю что и как дальше делать.
С БД я не работал, но сейчас очень нужно. Как вообще правильно заполнить таблицу с MySQL и сделать так, чтобы товары появились в OpenCart?
Буду благодарен любой помощи: Алгоритм действий, ссылка на инструкцию и т.п.

Answer (score 2):

Так просто ваша задачка не решается. Дело в том что опенкарт для хранения товаров использует множество таблиц, соответственно данные разнесены по ним.

Рекомендую вам использовать модуль для импорта данных, например: https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=17

Теоретически этого же можно достичь написав sql запросы, которые буду вставлять нужные данные в нужные таблицы, но для этого вам придется качественно разобраться в структуре таблиц и sql.

Comment: Спасибо, воспользовался модулем. Правда, оно импортировало данные непонятно куда. Вроде succesfull , но нигде этих товаров нет)
Я думал добавить базу товаров гораздо проще.. :\

Comment: А Вы структуру таблиц точно сопоставили? Проверьте в БД у товаров соответствие id магазина и языка, часто с этим проблемы бывают.

Answer (score 1):

Да, действительно, информация о товарах в ОС разнесена по разным таблицам в БД, причем нюансов весьма много. Вам удобнее использовать какой-нибудь модуль импорта. Со стандартными модулями импорта/экспорта у Вас тоже могут возникнуть трудности, потому что они "заточены" под определенную структуру таблиц, с одного магазина на OC выгрузить стандартную таблицу, в другой загрузить, к тому же, они не загружают изображения на сайт, только прописывают в БД путь к ним.
Если загрузить надо прайс произвольной структурой таблиц, то нужен более гибкий модуль импорта/парсер товаров. Советую посмотреть на бесплатный модуль [Liveimport](https://opencartforum.com/files/file/2977-liveimport-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82-excel-%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2/) . Очень гибкий, функциональный и простой в использовании: выбираете csv/xls файл и указываете модулю, 1 столбец - имя товара, 2 столбец - описание, 3 столбец пропустить, 5 столбец - атрибуты и т.д.. Можно использовать `php` функции, условия, добавлять переменные. Если разбить Ваш прайс на несколько частей, то даже на недорогом виртуальном хостинге проблем с импортом не будет.

Comment: Судя по вашему описанию - это то, что нужно. Сейчас буду пробовать, спасибо)

Comment: Пробуйте, решение рабочее, на форуме автор оказывает активную поддержку. Только повнимательнее и про резервные копии БД не забывайте. Советую почитать документацию к модулю, хотя бы мельком и посмотреть ветку на форуме, там есть полезные советы.